# How to fix Crapware font on PC

Tags: bloatware

I accidentally installed a piece of crapware using something called Rocketfuel. Now, a lot of sites have the same font as the installer did:

[image: Elder Scrolls Crappy Font]

How can I return the font to arial?

Comment: Use system restore and pick a restore point before you installed the problem software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser setting.  For IE go Tools/Internet Options/General Tab/at the bottom of the dialog there is a fonts button.

Other browsers will also have ways of setting the default font.